# BitmapSource MemoryStream leak with large images

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, memorystream, bitmapimage, bitmapsource

I'm working with image files over 1 GB, creating a `Bitmap` from a large `BitmapSource` and attempting to dispose of the original `BitmapSource`. The `BitmapSource` stays in memory. Normally this is an inconvenience as it is eventually collected, but with these large files, clearing the memory immediately is a necessity:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap;
using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
    enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapsource)); //large image
    enc.Save(outStream);
    bitmapsource = null;

    Bitmap temp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(outStream);
    bitmap = temp.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height), bm.PixelFormat);
    temp.Dispose();
}

GC.Collect();
GC.Collect();

//both bitmap and bitmapsource remain in memory
```

I've come across a work-around [here](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/04/memory_leak_with_bitmapimage_and_memorystream.html), but the `BitmapSource` still persists until much later in the pipeline.

Comment: I don't see you explicitly disposing bitmapsource?

Comment: that was a typo, corrected now